# how to print a certain amount of results on a single line

Tags: arrays, perl, count, format, newline

I want to print up to 10 results per line and then after 10 force a new line. How would I do this?

This is the code:

```
my @email;
my @gender;
my @state;

while ( <> ) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /,/;
push @gender, $fields[5];
push @email, $fields[3];
push @state, $fields[4];
}

#records
print "There are $_ records in this file\n" for scalar (@email-1);
print "\n";

#gender
my %count;
$count{$_}++ for @gender;
while( my ($gender => $count) = each %count) {
delete $count{gender};}
print "Male/Female distribution:\n";
print join(' ',%count), "\n";
print "\n";
#email



#states
my %scount;
$scount{$_}++ for @state;
while( my ($state => $scount) = each %scount){
delete $scount{state};}
print  join(' ',%scount), "\n";
```

and its result:

```
8 NC 292 OK 163 NY 901 VA 477 PA 195 NE 62 OH 711 WV 37 NM 10 MO 7 NH 77 MA  689 MN 431 TX 920 ME 81 NJ 673 RI 91 AL 230 KS 22 ND 31 FL 461 CT 305 CA 1262 IA 139 DE 33 CO 118 MI 378 IN 211 AR 163 IL 811 KY 11
```

So for example I would want a new line after `NM 10`.

Comment: Cab you provide the input file which will be more helpful and also the expected output ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `print  join(' ',%scount), "\n";` to:

```
my $n;
print map {$n++; $n % 10 ? "$_ $scount{$_} ":"$_ $scount{$_}\n"} keys %scount;
```

Answer (score 3):

Possibly a bit more readable:

```
my @results = %count;
while (@results) {
   print(join(" ", splice(@results, 10)), "\n");
}
```